# .load internet explorer error

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am using `.load` to load some data into a div. It works just fine but if I try to be specific and load a specific ID from the html IE won't load anything.

Ex.

```
$('div.myDiv').load('/example/example.htm');
```

works just fine but if I get specific on what to load like

```
$('div.myDiv').load('/example/example.htm #dogs');
```

IE loads nothing. is this not something that works in IE? The Jquery site doesn't say it doesn't. If it helps I'm using version jquery-1.5.min.js.

Comment: is there supposed to be a space between the page and the #?

Comment: why don't u try without space urself. believe me it wouldn't hurt

Comment: Yes there is meant to be a space. see here -> http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Please can you post the html with ID 'dogs'

Answer (score 1):

Does the html from /example/example.htm validate?

.load() will fail in ie if there are errors in the html.

Comment: Absolutely true. In my case a mismatched div. It was working in all modern browsers, but not in IE8.